# inheritance and smart pointers to instance of derived class

Tags: class, sockets, inheritance, smart-pointers

Currently I'm making simple chat program and I have problems with building classes.

These are two classes I made

Socket.h

```
class Socket;
using SocketPtr = shared_ptr<Socket>;

class Socket
{
private:
    SOCKET socket;
public:
    virtual int bind(const SocketAddress& toAddress) = 0;

    void setSocket(SOCKET sock);
    SOCKET getSocket();
};
```

TCPSocket.h

```
class TCPSocket;
using TCPSocketPtr = shared_ptr<TCPSocket>;

class TCPSocket : public Socket
{
private:
    friend class SocketUtil;
    TCPSocket(SOCKET sock);

public:
    ~TCPSocket();
    int bind(const SocketAddress& toAddress) override;
    int listen(int backLog = SOMAXCONN);
    int connect(const SocketAddress& toAddress);
    TCPSocketPtr accept(SocketAddress& fromAddress);
    int32_t send(const void* data, size_t length);
    int32_t receive(void* data, size_t length);
};
```

I'm trying to use instances of tcp socket with shared pointer but when I try to access member function of `TCPSocket` from `vector<SocketPtr>`, I can't access them because the type of the instance from the vector is `shared_ptr<Socket>`.

for now, I'm just using them after casting them to `shared_ptr<TCPSocket>` with `static_pointer_cast<TCPSocket>(exampleSocket)` but I think I'm not supposed to build classes like that.

Any help with building better classes for socket programming would be appreciated.

Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when i do this, i usually end up with two classes, an acceptor and a connection. the acceptor waits for a connection request and passes that off to a socket consumer that create a new connection thread and starts it listening. maybe something like [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/166167/c-linux-tcp-client-server-socket-wrapper).